# how to mock "new FileOutputStram()" written in public static method using Powermockito

Tags: junit, static-methods, fileoutputstream, powermockito

**Problem**: I am writing a test case for a method from which a public static method with below code is called:

```
final File file = new File(filePath);
    final OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
    out.write(bytes);
    out.close();
```

Now I need to mock the above calls.

**What I have written:-**

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception{
  File myFile = PowerMockito.mock(File.class);
  FileOutputStream outStream = PowerMockito.mock(FileOutputStream.class);

  PowerMockito.whenNew(File.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(myFile);        
  PowerMockito.whenNew(FileOutputStream.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(outStream);

  doNothing().when(outStream).write(Matchers.any());
  doNothing().when(outStream).close();
}

@Test
public void testMethod(){
  PowerMockito.mockStatic(StaticClassUtil.class);
  PowerMockito.when(StaticClassUtil.uploadFile(file.getBytes(), "dummy","dummy","dummy", null)).thenReturn("dummy");        
}
```

While debugging I found **No mock** object at line :

```
    final File file = new File(filePath);
```

Please suggest where I am getting wrong.

Comment: nice to read your comment, that is a learning experience for me and a strive to push myself too to reach the gold illuminator badge someday.:)

Comment: between you and me: given the fact that the Illuminiator badge is one of the really rare ones ... it is **incredibly** easy to get it. You simply answer a lot, and each time you get the first upvote on an answer, you edit the question to improve it. In other words: this badge is only about many answers and editing. Work and discipline. There are other badges that are **much** harder. For example one for having asked 100 questions that have +1 or more votes. Although I asked +60 questions ... I only have 30 or so with upvotes. In that sense: when you are interested in badges ...

Comment: work hard to get to the "reviewer" privilege ... and then you can get plenty of badges ... just by work/discipline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you missed one of the steps outlined in the [documentation](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/mockconstructor) - probably you forgot to use @PrepareForTest for File.class and FileOutputStream.class.

But the real answer: you don't necessarily *have* to call **new** directly in your code. You can turn to dependency injection frameworks to do that for you, or simply have an *OutputStream* **passed** into your method under test. Because then you only *pass* a mocked object, and your need to mock those pesky calls to `new()` vanish in thin air. And you can stick with good old Mockito instead of PowerMock(ito).

Comment: That's correct, I was certainly missing the File.class and FileOutputStream.class inside @PrepareForTest. I somehow moved ahead with it and will update mode details if found on it here later.